# Career Paths for Mathematics and Physics

Tags: career-path, university, degree

I'm just looking at the Mathematics & Physics program at University of Toronto (I think it's like Mathematical Physics, correct me if I'm wrong), I'm wondering what career paths I can choose if I take this program. 
Would this allow my to work in either field or just in the physics field? And would this allow me to go to grad school for either one I want, or is it restricted to one of the two fields?

If it makes any difference, here's a link to the university's program calendar:
http://www.artsandscience.utoronto.ca/ofr/calendar/crs_mat.htm

Thanks.

Comment: Go to which ever school that allows for the most flexibility in making your choice (i. e. The ability to take classes in both to decide which you like better). It is hard at this stage to say which is best until you decide on either mathematic or physics (mathematical physics as a subfield itself tends to be more in mathatics depts in my experience, but it depends on subfield).

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "career paths".  Outside academia, the possibilities are very broad and largely off-topic here.  Within academia, the main question is preparation for graduate school.  To get into a good graduate school, you'll typically have to go beyond the minimal requirements in even a very strong undergraduate program.  It's not likely that this problem by itself would prepare you well to apply to both math and physics grad schools.  However, you could presumably apply to whichever you prefer if you do some additional work (courses, summer research experience, etc.).

Comment: I'm an alumnus of the Mathematics and Physics specialist programme, if that's what you're looking at, and my (typically small) graduating year had people going into pure mathematics, applied mathematics, and physics graduate school; I myself am a pure mathematician with research interests related to mathematical physics. You'd definitely be able to apply for summer research in either department, but to some extent it would be best to figure out whether you want to do mathematics or physics by the end of second year, some time in third year at the latest...

Comment: ...so that you can get at much research experience and advanced (viz, graduate) level coursework as possible in the field you really want to graduate school in. If it's physics that you want, you should make sure that get enough lab courses in for the graduate schools you're applying to, since the math and physics specialist requires substantially fewer lab courses than the straight-up physics specialist. In any event, the traditional target audience for the programme is people preparing for grad school in mathematics (with a possible eye to mathematical physics) or in theoretical physics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For grad school applications, after making it through GRE cuts, the biggest decider will be the research that you've done. You'll want to develop programming skills in multiple languages, even if they don't cover them in class. For math and physics, MATLAB, Mathematica, and R are the most commonly used languages. If you don't find any research opportunities at Toronto, look for REU programs in the summer elsewhere. A math/physics degree can get you into grad school for math, physics, all manner of engineering (I went from astrophysics to aerospace engineering), chemistry. There are probably others as well.

Outside of grad school, the options are pretty varied. Again, if you can program that will open many more doors. My friends from undergrad in physics went on into banking/economics, General Electric, CERN, Seagate, Boeing, Lockheed Martin, the air force, and NASA. The majority, however, went to grad school. That keeps all those former options open, but also opens up the academic track (becoming a professor or a research scientist at all kinds of places like NIST or NOAA, but there are hundreds).